# When is a Fourier series analytic?

Tags: fourier-analysis, power-series, analyticity

By Fourier theory, every continuously differentiable function $f : S^1 \to \mathbf C$ admits a unique, uniformly convergent Fourier expansion

$$f(\theta) = \sum_{n\in \mathbf Z} a_n e^{in\theta}.$$

Does there exist a condition on the sequence $(a_n)$ equivalent to $f$ being *analytic* in $\theta$ in a neighborhood of $\theta=0$ (meaning that it has a convergent *Taylor* expansion $\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{\theta^m}{m!} b_m$ in a neighborhood of $0$)?

Writing $e^{in\theta} = \sum_{m\geq 0} \frac{(in)^m}{m!} \theta^m$, formally switching the two sums yields

$$f(\theta) = \sum_{n\in \mathbf Z} \sum_{m\geq 0} a_n \frac{(in)^m}{m!} \theta^m = \sum_{m\geq 0} \sum_{n\in \mathbf Z}  a_n \frac{(in)^m}{m!} \theta^m =  \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{\theta^m}{m!} b_m$$

where $$b_m = i^m\sum_{n \in \mathbf Z} a_n n^m.$$

(Remark that there is the formal "double-sided" Dirichlet series

$$L(f, s) = \sum_{n \in \mathbf Z} a_n n^{-s}$$

and formally, we can write $b_m = i^mF(-m)$.)

**First question**: is it true that $f(\theta)$ is analytic at $0$ if and only if:

1. the sums defining the $b_m$'s converge absolutely, and
2. the series $\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{\theta^m}{m!} b_m$ converges in a
   neighborhood of $0$, in which case it coincides with $f$ around $0$?

**Second question**: Can we determine whether $f$ is analytic around $0$ directly by looking at the sequence $(a_n)$?

Comment: Dear @user147263 : Thanks for pointing that out, I have modified the assumption on $f$. Do you happen to have a reference for the proof of the equivalence between analyticity on all of $S^1$ and rapid decay of $(a_n)$? Also, I'm curious to know why you think it is unlikely that there exists a criterion for analyticity at $0$. (My intuition for these things is rather poor.)

Comment: Dear @user147263: Thanks a lot for the proof sketch and for your intuition. I'll give it some thought. If you have the time to write that into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I begin with the **second question**. By looking at the coefficients $a_n$, you can easily see analyticity on **all** of $S^1$: it holds iff $|a_n|$ decay exponentially in both directions. This is Exercise I.4.4 from *An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis* by Y. Katznelson, 3rd edition:

> Show that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb T$ if and only if there exist constants $K>0$ and $a>0$ such that $|\hat f(j)|\le K e^{-a|j|}$.

Indeed, think in terms of complex plane, replacing $\exp(i\theta )$ by $z$. Two-sided exponential decay gives you convergent Laurent series in some annulus containing the circle. Conversely, analytic function on the circle can be extended to analytic function on some annulus; such a function is represented by a convergent Laurent series, which gives exponential decay of coefficients.

At the same time, Fourier coefficients are poorly suited to detect analyticity **at a point**, since they take into account the whole function. If you have a break in second derivative somewhere on the circle, that is going to dominate the behavior of coefficients; the contribution of analytic piece somewhere will be tiny in comparison.

---

**First question**: the conditions 1-2 are sufficient for analyticity in a neighborhood of $0$, but are not necessary. To begin with, the series 
$$b_m = i^m\sum_{n \in \mathbf Z} a_n n^m \tag{1}$$
converges for all $m$ iff $|a_n|$  decay faster than any power of $n$. This kind of decay is equivalent to $f$ being in $C^\infty(\mathbb T)$ (see section I.4 in Katznelson's book). So, if you have an analytic function in a neighborhood of $0$ that is not $C^\infty$ on the entire circle, the condition for $b_m$ does not make sense*.

(*) You could try to regularize the divergent series (1), but I think the regularization would amount to summing the Fourier series and then differentiating the sum.

*Sufficiency* can be established without rearranging the series. As noted above, the convergence of every series in (1) implies $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb T)$. We evaluate the derivatives of $f$ at $0$ just by  plugging in $\theta=0$ into the differentiated Fourier series. This gives Taylor coefficients, in terms of which the analyticity at  $0$ is characterized.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for.