# Are there any theorems linking periodic functions to the number of times they are differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, derivatives, periodic-functions

I was working through some Fourier series questions and I was wondering if the periodicity of a function has anything to do with the number of times it's differentiable. For instance, the elementary trigonometric functions are periodic and differentiable infinitely many times. I couldn't find anybparticular theorems or information about this and I was just wondering if there is any possible link between these two concepts.

Comment: Why would you exclude "piecewise functions"?  "Piecewise" is a property of the description of a function, not of the function itself.

Comment: "Excluding piecewise functions" makes no senses unless you have a definition of what you mean by a function being "piecewise", and I'm pretty sure you don't. Note that in order for "piecewise" to be a property _of a function_ your definition needs to be stated _only_ in terms of what the value of the function is at each input -- speaking about the particular form of the _description_ we happen to employ for specifying _which_ function we're talking about doesn't work for defining a property of the function _itself_.

Comment: Also note that, for example, $x\mapsto \sqrt{\sin^2 x}$ is periodic and not even differentiable once. And the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is periodic and not differentiable once _anywhere_.

Comment: Sorry, I thought piecewise functions were something else. To me, it looks as if there shouldn't be any link between the two conceots but I was just wondering because I couldn't exactly understand if the periodicity of the basic trigonometric functions have anything to do with their differentiability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell whether a function is "piecewise"; that is only an artifact of the limitations of how we (as humans) are able to write down an expression for the value of the function.

Anyways, just periodicity alone affords you very little. Indeed, arbitrary Fourier series are periodic, and the famous 
[Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is periodic, continuous and differentiable nowhere.

However, if you know something about the decay of the Fourier coefficients of our periodic function, then in fact it does imply something about differentiability.

> Theorem: Let $f \in L^2[-T,T]$ and suppose the $2T$-periodic Fourier series coefficients $a_n$ of $f$ satisfy
>   $$
> |a_n| \le C |n|^{-k-1-\epsilon}
> $$
>   for some $C, \epsilon > 0$. Then $f \in C^k$.

This generalizes the fact that sine and cosine are infinitely differentiable; their Fourier coefficients are all zero except the first few terms, so they have the maximum amount of coefficient decay.

Comment: I agree. I would like to add something (see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/801114) : the decay of Fourier coefficients could follow an exponential trend $a^{-n}$ instead of a negative power $n^{-k}$ trend. This characterize a $C^{\omega}$ (= analytic) function. See an example with the Poisson kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel