# If $|\hat{f}(k)| \leq e^{-|k|},$ then what can we say about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\{c_k\} \subset \mathbb C$ sch that $|c_k|\leq e^{-|k|}$ $(k\in \mathbb Z).$  We also assume that $f(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R.$

Put $f(x):= \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} c_k e^{ikx}$ $x\in \mathbb R.$

(We note that $f$ is periodic function on $\mathbb R,$ and  its Fourier series is absolutely convergent. Thus, $f$  is a continuous periodic on $\mathbb R.$

> **Question:**  Is $f$ is [real analytic](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function) at some point on $\mathbb R$? Is $g(x)= f(\arcsin (x/r))$ ($|x/r|<1$) is real analytic in the neighborhood of origin?

My thought: (1) We note that  series $\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} c_{k}e^{i k(s+it)}$... (A) converges  absolutely for $|t|<1, s \in \mathbb R$? 
Can we say the sum of series (A) is analytic extension of $f$?
(2) We also observe that  Fourier coefficient of $f:$ $|\hat{f}(k)|= |c_k| \leq e^{-|k|}$, have very nice decay.

Comment: According to the definition both in your link and the [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Definitions), it seems that real-valuedness is required for the notion of real-analyticity. But if we choose $c_k = \operatorname{sign}(k) e^{-|k|}$ so that $$ f(x) = i \frac{2e\sin x}{1 - 2e\sin x + e^2}, $$ then $f$ cannot be real-valued on any non-empty open subset of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801114/when-is-a-fourier-series-analytic , the first answer.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Thanks. I  agree. I have edited my question.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Thanks.  From that answer, I think the answer is positive. But I do not know how to prove that exercise by the book of Katznelson. Any idea? thanks..

Comment: @SangchulLee [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Definitions), that the coefficients $a_n$ are real is a mistake. They can of course be complex

Answer (score 2):

If $|c_k| < e^{-|k|}$ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{-k} z^k$ are complex analytic on $\{z  \in \mathbb{C}, |z| < e\}$ so that $\displaystyle F(z) =\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k z^k$ is complex analytic on $\{z  \in \mathbb{C}, 1/e <|z| < e\}$.

Thus $f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{i kx} = F(e^{ix})$  is complex analytic on $\{ x \in \mathbb{C}, Im(x) \in (-1,1)\}$

(complex-analytic is much stronger than real-analytic)

---

If you start from a continuous $2\pi$ periodic function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\hat{g}(k) = c_k$, it means that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ g(x) = f(x)$ and $g$ is real-analytic and **extends** to a complex analytic function $\{x \in \mathbb{C}, Im(x) \in (-1,1)\} \to \mathbb{C}$

---

I'm not sure why you want to look at $f(\arcsin (x/r))$, you should look at the [composition of analytic functions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=composition+of+analytic+functions).

Comment: Thanks. But $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, how can we talk of complex analytic function?

Comment: To conclude real analyticity of $f,$ do I need to go to some function $\tilde{f}$ defined on $\mathbb C$?

Comment: What is $m(x)$?

Comment: @abcd $Im(x)$ : imaginary part of complex number $x$. And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence explaining how a real analytic function on $(a,b)$ extends to a complex analytic function

Comment: @user192009: Thanks. Here $x\in \mathbb R, $ so $Im (x)=0$. Then why do we need $Im(x)$?

Comment: @abcd  See I edited, $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\{x \in \mathbb{C}, Im(x) \in (-1,1)\}$.

Comment: Nitpick: real-analytic $=$ restriction to $\Bbb R$ of complex-analytic. Complex-differentiable is much stronger than (even $\infty$ times) real-differentiable.